# Crystal: Class+ is not a class, it's a Class+

Tags: crystal-lang

While experimenting with the [online crystal compiler](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/cr) (which is awesome), I've run into an error which I can't seem to find an explanation for:

```
class Person
  class Current < self
  end

  class Destroyed < self
  end  
end
```

Error: `Person+ is not a class, it's a Person+`

If I change the code to

```
class Person
  class Current < Person
  end

  class Destroyed < Person
  end  
end
```

Then everything works fine.

If I just do

```
class Person
  class Current < self
  end      
end
```

Then everything works fine.

### Questions

1. What is a `Class+` ( / `Person+`... I'm assuming `Person` is a class)
2. It appears that *being inherited* is mutating the `Person` class in some way. What's going on here?

Comment: i'm guessing like many oop languages `self` (or `this`) refers to the instance.

Comment: @DanielA.White Hmm, so you're comment caused me to play around some more. It looks / sounds like a class inherits a type, rather than a class object? Maybe this is standard for typed languages, but I'm coming from a Ruby background and didn't realize this. Do you have any idea what the `Person+` message means? And why I'm able to inherit an object once? I re-read the Crystal Docs on types and inheritance. It doesn't seem like this is covered. The section on inheritance says that "a class inherits from another class" --> I interpret as inherits a class object (which, above, `self` is--I think).

Comment: The answer is simple: this is just a bug. Please report it on the crystal issue tracker. Inheriting a class does mutate the parent class in the compiler, and here that's causing this bug. This mutation should be invisible to the user, just an implementation detail. Here a bug in the compiler is exposing it to you by accident.

Comment: @RX14 ah, cool! Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RX14 stated in a comment, turns out this is a bug. Issue opened here: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5495